# Protect memory on x86-64

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86-64

I'm implementing a compiler which compiles a simulated processor's instruction set to code in x86 instructions. No physical processor exists which runs on the to be simulated instruction set; there is just the simulation on x86. When executing the compiled machine code (the simulation), I want to make sure that only memory designated for the simulation is read or written. This serves two purposes: 1) An access outside of the designated memory area could mean that I have a bug in my compiler. I want to find such bugs. 2) An access outside of the designated memory area can also mean that the source instructions that I compiled have a logical error and therefor try to access a memory address which does not exist in my simulation, thus an error should be raised.

In a simpler form, you can imagine my code to look like this:

```
void simulate(char* designated_memory, size_t len) {
    // code intended to access *designated_memory till *(designated_memory + len - 1) only
}
```

Is there a way on x86-64 and/or in linux to enforce that `simulate()` can only access its own stack and `designated_memory`, and any other access would generate an error. E.g. the code could look like this:

```
restrict_access_to(designated_memory, designated_memory + len - 1);
simulate(designated_memory, len);
remove_access_restriction();
```

A solution in C would be nice; asm is fine, too.

**UPDATE**:

Following Jester's comments, I came to try out this:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <malloc.h>
    #include <sys/mman.h>

    int main() {
        size_t pagesize = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);

        printf("pagesize...........: %lu\n", pagesize);

        char* m;
        size_t len = 12345;
        len = (len + pagesize - 1) / pagesize * pagesize;
        posix_memalign(&m, pagesize, len);

        printf("page aligned memory: %lx - %lx\n", (unsigned long) m, (unsigned long) m + len);

        printf("protecting 0 till m..."); fflush(stdout);
        mprotect(0, (size_t) m, PROT_NONE);
        printf("done\n");

        printf("protecting (m + len) till ?..."); fflush(stdout);
        mprotect(m + len, 0x7fffffff, PROT_NONE);
        printf("done\n");

        printf("trying to modify memory..."); fflush(stdout);
        *(m - 1000) = 5;
        printf("done: %i\n", *(m - 1000));

        free(m);
    }
```

Which outputs:

```
pagesize...........: 4096
page aligned memory: 9ac000 - 9b0000
protecting 0 till m...done
protecting (m + len) till ?...done
trying to modify memory...done: 5
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I think that this shows that modifying data outside of the allowed area still works, but that should not happen.

Comment: downvoter mind stating a reason?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but this question can't be answered as asked. It asks for help implementing a solution without saying what problem it's asking for a solution to. I can think of lots of things that might be answers and might be irrelevant, and can't tell which is which.

Comment: For example, is copying the data to an area of memory carefully aligned so that the end of the valid data falls outside the mapped page an answer? I can't tell if that solves your problem because I don't know what your problem is.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz does my update help?

Comment: You can use [mprotect](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mprotect) with a page granularity. The problem is, you need to turn off access to other pages, not turn on access to the given range. Forking a separate process might be helpful.

Comment: @Jester I think I have a very rough idea what you mean, but can you elaborate? E.g. can I align my memory beginning with a page beginning (how?) and then use `mprotect(0, designated_memory, PROT_NONE);` to protect any memory below it?

Comment: Yeah. You can use [posix_memalign](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memalign) or just everyday `malloc` and some pointer arithmetic.

Comment: You can create the memory as an array, represent all addresses as offsets, and have the compiler generate bounds checks before each operation that uses memory.  In C++, `std::vector` does this for you.  In addition to the other ideas about poisoning pages, you could stick a canary value after the last valid address and check if it was overwritten.

Comment: Not clear why you need this, if you simulate some CPU, then at start you give to it some bank of memory, which look like physical memory for guest, and as chunk of virtual memory for you, and in your instruction iterpretator, you can just check that you are access to the chunk of memory that you give simulated CPU at start.

Comment: @user1034749 i do not use an interpreter. i use a compiler to compile the simulated instructions to x86 instructions. i do not want to include all the range checking in the compilation to x86 instructions for performance reasons. i might have to do this in the end though if pages are not accurate enough.

Comment: @Lorehead i also want to forbid reads from out of range addresses, so things like 0xdeadbeef as markers won't be sufficient. for range checking see my reply to user...'s comment.

Answer (score 1):

> i do not use an interpreter. i use a compiler to compile the simulated >instructions to x86 instructions. i do not want to include all the range checking >in the compilation to x86 instructions for performance reasons.

So your task is very similar to what does `qemu`, when it does emulation for example `ARM` on `x86`, it convert `arm` instructions to `x86` instructions,
so I suggest you look at source code of qemu: http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page

The next very similar to your project is `valrgrind`, 
the way how `valgrind` works is very similar to what you do:
it execute program on some kind of virtual `cpu` to check memory accesses,
and to speedup things it uses `jit` (http://valgrind.org/).

And the last opensource project, that solve similar problems to your is
https://github.com/google/sanitizers/tree/master/address-sanitizer

Yes, it is instrumented code, but the result works much faster then `valgrind`,
the idea how to instrument generated code, but leave performance on suitable level you can find in this video about `asan` internals:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q2C2lP8_tNE

Comment: Thank you for sharing the links and ideas. Though they are not a direct answer to the question, maybe they lead me in a much better direction.

Answer (score 1):

If you are executing arbitrary assembly instructions in user-space code, there isn't really a way to enforce protection of the memory -- memory protection generally requires having the ability to activate kernel-mode flags on the CPU.

However, since you are writing a simulator, and compiling another language to a set of assembly instructions of your choosing, you have a different option: control the instructions being emmitted. Instead of emitting raw memory access instructions for simulated memory accesses, have the simulation compiler replace instructions which would access memory with instructions which call a memory-access function of your own design, and implement memory access protection in that function. This could also be done as Lorehead states by having the memory region be something like a `std::vector`.

Note that just replacing normal move instructions with your own move function isn't really sufficient to protect your own wrapper code from being hacked by "simulated" code. If your simulation emits raw jump commands, then it can be broken by simulated code which jumps outside of the simulation. Or by carefully planned push/pop instructions which cause the wrapper code to return to other simulator code later, after you should have left the simulation.

To actually be (somewhat) safe (this is by no means exhaustive, or guaranteed to be sufficient to make the simulated code safe), you would need to make sure that your simulation compiler generates safe code; things which affect what memory may be accessed, including mov, jump, push, pop, call, and ret would need to be replaced with function calls that perform equivalent actions safely, rather than just executing assembly code that you can't trust.

You would also need to make sure to wrap this in code which saves your registers for your outer program, since the inner code may arbitrarily change their contents.

Comment: Right. Just make sure your compiler cannot emit instructions that access memory without first checking whether that access is permissible.

Comment: There are other things besides memory to watch out for too. Interrupts for example. If the compiled code can execute interrupts, then it can, for example, open a file, write a new malicious program to that file, and tell the kernel to execute the malicious file as a new process outside or the simulator. Or reexec the simulator without the container to wrap it.

Answer (score 1):

You write that you don’t want to add runtime bounds checking for performance reasons.  I suggest you look closely at the actual runtime cost and reconsider: it’s literally a single instruction if you use indirect addressing (`ja`) which even the simplest branch predictors can get right if you put the exception handler last.  If you can recognize and optimize (some) loops, you can do one bounds check before the loop, instead of one before every access inside the loop.

If you really can’t afford this overhead, one option you can try is to compile the executable and fork off a process that has no other memory in its address space.  If you’re going to run in a process that uses the stack, though, it’s theoretically possible that native code could clobber the stack.  You can also make it impossible to access memory outside the address space if you make the size of the address space exactly 2^16 or 2^32 bytes and have the compiled code access it with that size register.  Otherwise, you’re stuck trying to poison every single other page of the address space.

Comment: quote: "it’s literally a single instruction if you use indirect addressing (ja) which even the simplest branch predictors can get right if you put the exception handler last." - Maybe I'm wrong here to think that the performance cost would be too high. Indeed what you say - just one instruction and good branch prediction - does sound convincing. This might sound trivial to you and unnecessary, but can you give a short code example for me to see the concept you are talking about in more detail, please?

Comment: @DanielS. Okay, the one-instruction version is `bound`. But a practical implementation might label its exception handler `OutOfBounds:`, then insert before a memory access instructions such as `cmp addre, bound`; `jnb OutOfBounds`. Your memory accesses are probably offsets from `ebx`, but in 32-bit mode, you might in theory give the memory space its own segment.

Comment: No worries, this was not a test. I'm sincerely interested in the code. If you can put some together, I would be more than glad to see it, even if it's not just one additional instruction for the check.

Comment: @DanielS. I did implement runtime array bounds checking in Java for an undergrad compilers course using a similar method, but I don’t have that code any longer and it isn’t a MCVE. I’ll have to get back to you on that.